# How do I create a photobox for image?

Tags: views, panels, media

Can anyone please guide me on how do I create a photobox that contains image and I wanted to display that image on landing page.

I have created content type as an Image. But, I don't know how to display that image in landing page.

I am new to Drupal. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: welcome to Drupal :) But then I right away have say *sorry*, but I think it's not really a good idea to ask people to "*guide you on how to…*". People here try to ask straight questions and give straight answers – if they can.

About your actual question: for displaying a specific page as your front page a.f.a.i.k. all you have to do is to go to **Configuration** > then **Site Information** > then you can adjust the **Default front page setting** by entering the path of any of your pages… Hope this helps…?

And last but not least I can just recommend you spend some time with some basic recources and tutorials – for example [Drupal 7 – the Essentials](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/the-essentials-7) is sheer greatness! And the [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation) has almost every important aspect of Drupal listed, that one could need for a start…

Answer (score 0):

with tillinberlin answer I would like to add.
tillinberlin told you about landing page. here I want to tell you about display images

Even I am doing same thing I gone through the [YoxView](https://www.drupal.org/project/yoxview) and [fancyBox](https://www.drupal.org/project/fancybox) modules to view of my images.

choose one to view your images which best suites for you.

Answer (score 0):

@tillinberlin

I don't have question for "displaying a specific page as your front pag".

I asked question for "**Image.**" Anyways Thanks for some information though!!

I have created specific image style for my image box by going into "Configuration -> Image Styles.

I have created Content Types for image.

For example lets say, Content type is: "Top Left Image".
I have defined fields called "Image Name" and "Image" into "Top Left Image".

Then I have created one view called " Top Left Imagebox".
In view, I have defined fields called Content: Image.

Formatter: Image

Image Style: Selected specific image style.

Link Image to: Nothing

I have used **Rewrite Rule** to make a view that displays image or video filed if present.

No Results Behavior: **[field_image]**

Checked - **Hide rewriting if empty**

Checked Rewrite the output of this field.

I have defined this view into my Landing Panel Page. But, somehow **image is not displaying into the browser.**

Yes, I am using **Drupal-7**.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To get an image or any other field as content you should:

- Edit your page.tlp.php
- if theres only one image and if your field has a machine name 'image':
  **$image_url** = file_create_url($node->image["und"][0]["uri"]);

> **$node** is where your content is stored
>
> **"image"** followed by "->" is your machine name where you get by array all values related to your field
>
> and final **file_create_url()** converts your uri to url like the method's name suggests

To output your image you can do something simple like this:

```
<?php
   (...)
      $image_url = file_create_url($node->image["und"][0]["uri"]);
      echo "<img src='{$image_url}' width='300' />";

   (...)
?>
```

You can always add a module like this one [Photobox](https://www.drupal.org/project/photobox) to get the job done. I am assuming that your are using D7. please precise your Drupal's version next time :)